# jQuery Select Array in a Selector

Tags: jquery, arrays, greasemonkey

So I'm working on a Greasemonkey UserScript for Clients From Hell http://clientsfromhell.net/ and I'm stuck on something.

The script allows a user to navigate through posts on the page using the J and K keys. I'm trying to mimic the site http://9gag.com/ navigation. There are 10 posts on the page and each of them have the class `post` so I thought a simple selector would work and give me the posts in an array. This is how I want the code to work:

```
postScroll = $('.post')[post].offset().top - 25;
```

So far I've been doing this and it's been working,

```
postScroll = $('.post:nth-child(' + post + ')').offset().top - 25;
```

I just wanted to know if there's a right way of doing what I tried in my first code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.eq(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) like this:

```
postScroll = $('.post').eq(post).offset().top - 25;
```

This gets the jquery object representing the index in the matches array that you passed in. Doing `$(selector)[index]` or [`$(selector).get(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) both get the DOM element, not the jQuery object, which you'll need for [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).

Comment: You sir, are a gentlemen and a scholar. Thanks for the help!